# Modified Takagi function

Tags: real-analysis

I am interested in a modified version of the Takagi function. Particularly, I am interested in showing that it is not differentiable at non <s>dyadic</s> triadic points.

Previously I proved (for the [Takagi function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve#Definition) $g$ where in the notation I denote the $s$ on Wikipedia by $h$) that $g'(x)$ does not exist where

$$ g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {1\over 2^n }h(2^n x) = \sum_{n \ge 0}h_n(x)$$

and  $h_n(x) = (1/2)^n h(2^n x)$ and  $h(x)=|x|$ on $[-1,1]$ and extend it to $\mathbb R$ by defining $h(2+x) = h(x)$. ($h_n$ is a sawtooth function)

It is not difficult: If $x$ is not dyadic it is possible to show that $g'(x)$ does not exist by showing

(i) that $|g_m' (x) - g_{m+1}'(x)|=1$ and

(ii) that $$  {g(y_m) - g(x) \over y_m - x} < g'_m (x) < {g(x_m) - g(x) \over x_m - x}$$

Here $g_m$ denotes the finite sum $\sum_{n=1}^m h_n(x)$.

Now consider the modifed Takagi function: $$g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {1\over 2^n }h(\color{red}{3}^n x)  $$

Again I want to show that $g'(x)$ does not exist if $x$ is not dyadic. It is easy to see that $|g_m' (x) - g_{m+1}'(x)|={3^{m+1} \over 2^{m+1}}$ therefore $g_m'(x)$ is not a Cauchy sequence and does not converge.

I am having trouble showing

$$  {g(y_m) - g(x) \over y_m - x} < g'_m (x) < {g(x_m) - g(x) \over x_m - x}$$

for this modified $g$ because $h_n$ is not $0$ if $n$ is large enough. Nonetheless $g_m$ is still piecewise linear and linear on $[x_m,y_m]$ so that

$$ g'_m (x) = {g_m(y_m) - g_m (x) \over y_m - x} > {g_m(y_m) - g (x) \over y_m - x} $$

What to do about $g_m (y_m)$?

Comment: what is $g_m$? Do you want to prove non differentability for dyadic $x$ or for non dyadic $x$?

Comment: @Norbert Thank you for your comment. $g_m$ is the finite sum $$ \sum_{n=1}^m h_n(x)$$ I want to show the non differentiability at non dyadic points.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\langle \langle x\rangle \rangle = \min_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}|x-n|$.   [Lagarias](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.4205) defines the Takagi function as

$$ \tau(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \langle \langle 2^n x \rangle \rangle$$

However we could replace $2$ with $3$ or any real number $a \geq 2$, and get another self-similar function:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{a^n} \langle \langle a^n x \rangle \rangle$$

The introduction says that Knopp analyzed functions connection various scales

$$ F(x) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{a^n} \phi ( b^n x )\rangle$$

and showed in 1918 $F(x)$ has *no finite derivative*  when $\frac{b}{a} \geq 1$  which is your case, $a=2,b=3$.

---

Look at Theorem 8.1 to 8.3 - a result proven by Kohno in 1987 - that

$$|\tau(x+h) - \tau(x)| \approx h \log_2 \tfrac{1}{h}$$

Let's try to estimate $ F(x+h) - F(x)$  in some kind of way. Let $h = \tfrac{1}{3^n}$. If $m > n$ s a finite sum

$$ \langle \langle 3^m (x+h) \rangle \rangle - \langle \langle 3^m x \rangle \rangle = 0$$

If $m < n$   we get non-zero contributions to the difference:

$$ \tfrac{1}{2^m} \big|\langle \langle 3^m (x+h) \rangle \rangle - \langle \langle 3^m x \rangle \rangle \big| 
= \frac{1}{2^m}\frac{1}{3^{n-m}}$$

These terms can't possibly cancel each other out.  However, maybe you can use a [Hölder exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition) and have something like:

$$ |F(x+h)-F(x)| \approx h \log_3 \tfrac{1}{h}$$

which accounts for the oscillatory behavior of your function.

---

**[Theorem](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/131bh.1.03s/week45.pdf)** (or
see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85324/derivative-of-infinite-sum)) If $\sum h'_n(x)$ is uniformly  convergent on $ [a,b]$ and $\sum h_n(x)$ converges at one point, then $\frac{d}{dx} \sum h_n(x) = \sum \frac{dh_n}{dx} (x)$.

Here $ |h_n(3^n x) | \leq 1$ and your sum is uniformly bounded by $2$ and all the terms are positive:

$$ \left|\sum \frac{1}{2^n}h_n(3^nx)\right| \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{1}{2^n} =2 $$

So your series is uniformly convergent.  All the $h_n(x)$ are differentiable off the **ternary** points, $\mathbb{Z}[\tfrac{1}{3}]$.

The derivatives are not uniformly convergent:

$$ \left| \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{2^n}h_n(3^nx)\right|
 = \left| \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n h'_n(3^n x)\right| = \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n \to \infty $$

Actually this works to your advantage... since we have shown this modified function has divergent terms in the derivative.

---

Wikipedia: [Takagi function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve)

arXiv:1112.4205 [The Takagi Function and Its Properties](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.4205)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Did you mean "uniformly convergent on $[a,b]$" in the "Theorem"?

Comment: Also, isn't $|h_n(3^n x) | \le 1$ rather than $|h_n(3^n x) | < 1$?

Comment: @blue Your function is defined everywhere, but it has no derivative at any point whether it is $\tfrac{m}{3^n}$ or not, since the derivative of each term $\left(\tfrac{3}{2}\right)^2$ is unbounded.

Comment: I'm trying to find the relevant result in the arxiv paper you link to but I can't find it. Could you point out to me where the paper treats the case in my question? Also, could you please elaborate how you deduce from $\sum f_n'$ does not converge that $\left ( \sum_n f_n (x) \right )'$ does not exist? Thank you.

Comment: On which page is ${b \over a}\ge 1$ mentioned? I am looking at page 3 where it is mentioned that "...a later result of Behrend ...establishes no finite derivative for integer $b$ and $0 < a < 1$, having $ab \ge 1$, *with some specific exceptions*..." It does not specify whether my example is one of these exceptions?

Comment: I think it's common sense at this point.  You are summing functions of slope $(\tfrac{3}{2})^n$ there is no way they can cancel out.