# Comfirmation of third derivative of symbolic equation including summation

Tags: derivatives, summation, solution-verification, symbolic-computation

With previous help I was able to find the first derivative of an equation for a work project. Now I'm after the second and third derivative, for use in a program to find the maximum (Which I must do from scratch). The following is what I believe them to be. Would someone please check my answers.

$$
f(\theta)= -\ln \left(\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T} e^{r_t\theta}\right)
$$
$$
f(\theta)= -\ln \left( \sum_{t=1}^{T} e^{r_t\theta} \right) + \ln(T)
$$
$$
f'(\theta)=-\frac{\sum_{t=1}^{T} r_te^{r_t\theta}}{\sum_{t=1}^{T} e^{r_t\theta}}
$$
$$
f'(\theta)=-\frac{h(\theta)}{g(\theta)}
$$
$$
f''(\theta)=-\frac{g(\theta)h'(\theta)-h(\theta)g'(\theta)}{g'(\theta)^2}
$$
$$
f''(\theta)=\frac{(\sum_{t=1}^{T} r_te^{r_t\theta})^2 - \sum_{t=1}^{T} e^{r_t\theta}\sum_{t=1}^{T}
r_t^2e^{r_t\theta}}{(\sum_{t=1}^{T} e^{r_t\theta})^2}
$$

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's right, and holds if $T$ is not a function of $\theta$, and if it is a constant, $T$ is finite. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85324/derivative-of-infinite-sum).

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I can move onto checking the find_maxima(theta) program logic.

Comment: I did make one typographical error that went unnoticed. The first derivative f'(), is actually not a derivative but f() in a different form. So f'''() is actually just f''() which as it turns out is all I needed. I've updated the question.

Comment: @LookLeft I will edit my answer tomorrow, it's late now.